# what options do I have for replacing a microwave foot?

Tags: microwave-oven

I've looked on eBay and have not found the exact model microwave foot for sale.

Comment: Are you referring to a plastic or rubber piece on the outside bottom?

Comment: there is not really such a thing as a `microwave foot` ... search for `small appliance foot`

Comment: You may not find the exact height, so get teh closest one, and build or cut off a bit.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are referring to a plastic or rubber piece on the outside bottom of a countertop microwave oven, they are really nothing special. You can either find one of the exact same height as the others (assuming you still have 3 out of 4 attached), or a complete set of 4 that are *taller* than the existing ones (assuming you still have 3 out of 4 attached) or you can get a complete set of 4 of any height if you can figure out how to remove the others.

These attach in various ways:

- Peel and stick
- Crazy glue (or other glue, but cyanoacrylate is usually easiest for this type of thing)
- Screw - I do *not* recommend this for a microwave oven or similar appliance, because you would have to make a hole in the case and you don't know how far you can put a screw in before hitting something important like wiring.

Some "feet" are actually designed to make things easy to slide so that, for example, you can have a coffee machine sit towards the back of the counter and easily pull it forward to use it without lifting it up. For a microwave oven I recommend something that is designed to stay in one place and *not* be easy to move. A not-quite-random (but not personally tested) example [from Amazon](https://amzn.to/482ZOa5):

[image: Set of 4 feet]